# How to clone a DOM element and keep it synchronized?

Tags: javascript

I want to deep clone a DOM element and keep it synchronized. I.e.:

```
var clone = originalElement.clone(true);
```

Thus, whenever `originalElement` has any children added or removed, I want to add (clone) or remove them from the clone element. And whenever any children changes their attributes or text, I want to update it in the clone.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to clone it? As it sounds now, it would be better if you use some reference to the dom element instead, in that case, if you change one place it will change in the other...

Comment: This can be done using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)